# ReactNative: displaying the image from the local storage is not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I am building an IOS application using ReactNative. My app needs to display image from the local file system or gallery or the ones captured by the camera. But it is not working. I am displaying something like this.

```
<FastImage
                            style={[imageStyle.image]}
                            source={{ uri: source }}
                        />
```

This is the library I am using, https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image. The source value is something like this.

[image]

As you can see, it is not displaying the image. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

I also tried prepending "file://" to the path as well. It did not work either.

Comment: did you try to add source of image with require like source={require('dummy.png')} ?

Comment: But those photos are taken by the camera or from gallery. Do I have to do something like source={require(source)}?

Comment: When I did require(source), it is not working.

Comment: since contributor says local images not supported,  we need some workaround. https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/160. Are you sure your path to the image is correct?

Comment: Are you sure of the existance of the file? As i can see, the image is in cache, it might be deleted. Can you check with react-native-fs library?

Comment: Hello, yes the file exist.

Comment: @UğurEren, the file does exist on the system.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a local file. The source prop should have a file path instead of a uri. Let’s say your image is located at ./Images/myImage.png. Try this:

source={require("./Images/myImage.png")}

Comment: This does not work because when I put in the variable for the path, it is failing when I compile the app. The paths are dynamic.

Comment: Could you copy the error code? Is it an invariant violation?

Comment: It basically saying file does not exist when I tried to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
const directoryPath = Platform.OS === 'android' ? RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;

<FastImage
  style={YOUR_IMAGE_STYLE}
  source={{uri: `file://${directoryPath}/${YOUR_IMAGE_FILE_NAME}`}}
/>
```

PS: on Android, must use `file://`

PS: Need enable fs permission, ref to [ENOENT: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), open '/storage/emulated/0/Download/](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/941) on Android, and [IOS file downloaded not able to be located on device](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/897#issuecomment-759577180) on iOS.